# Removing Empty Lines from a file

Tags: regex, string, powershell

How can I delete with PowerShell empty lines and and initial space of not empty line in PowerShell within this "code-block"

```
$DIR = "C:\Users\cas\Documents..."
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $DIR) {
    (Get-Content -Path $file) |
        ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "&quot;", """" } |
        ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "<[^>]*>", "" } |       # removes xml-code
        ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\s+\r\n+', "`r`n" } | # <= this line doen't work
        Set-Content -Path $file
}
```

The solutions I found do use a different context, how can it be done here using regex?

I found the solution myself, here it is:

```
      foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $DIR){ 
      (Get-Content -Path $file) | 
      ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "&quot;", """" } |  
      ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "<[^>]*>", "" } |   # removes xml-code
      ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } |                         # removes empty lines
      Set-Content -Path $file
  }
```

Comment: Please post an answer if you found a solution on your own! :-)

Comment: I thought I did - but here it comes!

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content` will already have split the file by line endings, so `` `r`n `` won't match anything.

Just filter the lines out using `Where-Object`:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $DIR){ 
    (Get-Content -Path $file) |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "&quot;", """" } |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "<[^>]*>", "" } |
    Where-Object {-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)} |
    Set-Content -Path $file
}
```

Comment: Hmm - this doesn't do it :(

Comment: @gooly What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Version:  5.1.14409.1005